# How to convert streamsize to other or how to pass streamsize value to vector?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I have a problem i need to pass streamsize value to vector. if i'm not pass it to fixed size. it will overhead with emplace_back with thousand element. the error compiler is possible cause lost data.

```
ifstream input(i_inputFilePath, ios::binary);
if (input.is_open())
{
    ofstream output(o_outputFilePath, ios::binary);
    std::array<char, 1024> buffer;
    while (true) {
        input.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        streamsize dataSize = input.gcount();
        if (dataSize) 
        {
            std::vector<char> data(dataSize); // here the problem
            for (DWORD i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
            {
                data.emplace_back(buffer[i]);
            }
            std::rotate(data.begin(), data.begin() + 1, data.end());
            output.write(data.data(), dataSize);    
        }
        else 
        { 
            output.close();
            input.close();
            break;
        }   
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "File is not exist";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also learn how to create a [mcve]. And if asking about build error, please include the copy-pasted full and complete output, and add a comment in the code to show where it happens.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude its already full. i edited my question with comment to point to problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a single integer argument to the constructor of `std::vector` (as in `std::vector<char> data(dataSize);`) is will default-construct that many elements in it and its size will be the integer passed.

If you then `emplace_back` into it, it will increase its size, not overwrite the already constructed elements.

If you want to `emplace_back` all your elements, simply do so, no need to pass the final size to the constructor:

```
std::vector<char> data;
```

Most implementations of `std::vector` will not reallocate on each `emplace_back`, but will e.g. double the allocated space each time it runs out of space. Therefore this will not really be that bad on average.

If you are concerned about reallocations, then you can force the vector to pre-allocate space with

```
data.reserve(dataSize);
```

This will not actually construct any elements but make sure the necessary space is allocated in advance.

If you are getting an error message about the conversion from `std::streamsize` to `std::size_t`, then this is a false-positive, because in this particular case you know that `dataSize` can only have values ranging from `0` to `1024`. The compiler is correct in warning that `dataSize`'s type is signed and could therefore be holding a negative value that can not be represented by `std::size_t`, which is unsigned.

You can test whether this assumption is correct with something like

```
streamsize dataSize = input.gcount();
if(dataSize < 0 || dataSize > buffer.size()) {
    throw std::range_error("dataSize has unexpected value!");
}
data.reserve(static_cast<std::size_t>(dataSize));
```

This makes sure that `dataSize` is not accidentally negative or larger than expected (if it is, it will throw an exception) and otherwise it will hint at the compiler that you really want to do the narrowing conversion with the explicit cast, which should suppress the warning/error message.

Comment: i know but it keep resize. it will make overhead if 1 million element keep resize by 1 to fit.  why the vector need to keep resize if i know the buffer size?

Comment: the problem the streamsize dataSize don't want to allow convert. it same with data.reserve(dataSize)

Comment: i use visual studio 2017 community with language c++17. unicode code. and MT Build. is there something wrong iwth my config?

Comment: i check it to in my compile streamsize is typedef long long. but when i crreate long long variabel and initiliziation with streamsize. sampe result **can't convert possible lose data.**

Comment: my currently work code is i rework itu not using vector instead manual dynamic allocate with new. but i need to implement rotate by ownself

Comment: @stephen.hawk No don't use manual allocation. It doesn't solve the issue at all and causes more. Read my previous comment.

Comment: i need to check my visual studio config. maybe, thats make false error.

Comment: @Swordfish Is it better now? Though I think the test is not really required here, because gcount is guaranteed to give a result inside these bounds.

Comment: @eukaryota Very nice! \*thumbsup\*